# Eclipse: copying a warning to the clipboard

Tags: eclipse, cut-and-paste

How do you copy a warning from a specific line in Eclipse to the clipboard? I can see it with mouseover, I just can't seem to copy it.

In my "Problems" pane, I have a whole bunch of warnings and can't figure out how to isolate the one for a particular line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see it on mouseover, you can also move the mouse to hover over the warning message itself, and it becomes selectable.

Equivalently, you can press F2 (unless you changed your shortcut keys), which will focus the problem panel that popped up when you moused over the problem. And again, from here you can select the text and copy it.

Or copy with ctrl+c from the problems panel.

Or Properties from the problems panel, and then copy from there.

Maybe I didn't understand the problem...

Comment: The F2 did the trick. I use a pen tablet + somehow your first suggestion didn't work. (Java + Wacom tablets have issues. :( sigh. )

Comment: In order to copy it from the problems panel (my first choice before I posted this question), I'd need to *find* it in the problems panel, which was a needle in a haystack.

Comment: @Jason S, so then I suppose the F2 option isn't exactly "equivalent" like i suggested, it's better... it's the cross-platform solution. aahhh, the nuisances of quirks.